# Returning vector<string> inside a function or recursive_directory_iterator. Unhandled exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

```
vector<string> ReturDir(const string& s)
{
    vector<string> r;
    for (auto &p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(s))
    {
        if (p.is_directory()) r.push_back(p.path().string());
    }
    return r;
}
```

Fails miserably, why?
Ive tried everything, obviously I havent learned the true power of C++.
When I do it in plain main() that for loop works, but inside a function it doesn when calling from main().

> Unhandled exception at 0x76824192 in...
>   std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location

Thats what I thought.
How do I fix this, is it the vector and not the recursive_directory_iterator that causes the problem?

Comment: I have never used a `recursive_directory_iterator`, but, reading the info about it, I would have used an `auto& p`, not an `auto p` at the for loop. If not, the compiler will try to make an object copy.

Comment: Yes the correct is auto &p. i actually tried differnt things, and the original post should have included &. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

What does the exception say? There are lots of reasons why directory iteration might fail - lack of permissions being the most common one.

When I run this on my Mac, iterating over my home directory, I get an exception with the message:

> error: in recursive_directory_iterator::operator++(): attempting recursion into "./Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary": Operation not permitted

(catch the exception; print out the string from the `what()` call)

Comment: I used open with pipe which caused alot of problems with the code, so it wasnt actually the code itself inside the function.